# Change html page position when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I open my html, I would like to see a content of the first Home `div`.

When I'm opening it, the page is blank, and I need to click on Home `href` to see its content.

What can i do to see it when it loads?

HTML:

```
<div id="nav1">
    <a href="#home">HOME</a>
</div>
<div id="nav1">
    <a href="#gallery">GALLERY</a>
</div>
<div id="nav1">
    <a href="#s1">IMPORT</a>
</div>
<div id="nav1">
    <a href="#s2">ABOUT ME</a>
</div>
<div id="nav1">
    <a href="#s3">CONTACT</a>
</div>      
<div class="target">
    <div id="home">asddsa</div>
    <div id="gallery">asdfgaasd</div>
    <div iv="s1">some1</div>
    <div id="s2">some2</div>
    <div id="s3">some3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.target {
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 800px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    min-height: 600px;
}

.target > div {
    display: none;
}

.target > div:target{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to navigate it to `#home`.

Comment: And how to do that? I cannot into JS

Answer (score 0):

Use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location):

```
<script>
    window.location = "#home";
</script>
```

Jump link:

```
<a href="#home">HOME</a>
```

The script runs on load and navigates to the link

Comment: @krispi Now that's what is called JavaScript.